# jQuery .scrollTo() blocks UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#index a").click(function (e) {
            $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, {duration: 2000});
        });
```

The function works OK just that after the slide it blocks the page for a short while (1-2 seconds) After that it comes back to normal.

How can I remove this UI block ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#index a").click(function (e) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 2000);
});
```

Solves the problem